# How do i print palindrome words in a string?

Tags: java

So i decided to print all palindrome words in a string. I didnt use arrays or the method to find palindrome of only 3-character-words.Here is my code,the problem being,it prints out nothing

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Pa{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        char b;
        int i,a;
        String st="";/to extract a word
        s=s+" ";
        String t="";/to extract the reverse of the word
        a=s.length();
        for(i=0;i<a;i++){
            b=s.charAt(i);
            if(b!=' '){
                st=st+b;/word
                t=b+st;/reversed word
            } else { 
                if(st.equals(t)){
                    System.out.println(st);
                }
            st="";
            t="";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong and would not appreciate the split or 3-word palindrome finder options or the normal even-or-odd only palindrome finding options.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should really break out the palindrome logic to a separate function. That would make everything so much easier to debug. Create the function  bool isPalindrome(String s).

Comment: @Rockabyee Java You have a small error in one line of your program.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a String is a Palindrom a single loop is sufficient

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(String word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length() - (i + 1))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can split your input string at every whitespace like `input.split("\\s")` and check for every word if it's a palindrom

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check palindrome:

```
private static boolean isPalindrom(String s) {
    return s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is below. Instead of appending b to the reversed string, you're appending it to the normal string.

```
        b=s.charAt(i);
        if(b!=' '){
            st=st+b; 
            t=b+st; // This should be t=b+t
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//input-mom gives me a pen(reverse-mom sevig em a nep)(checking each word by reverse)//
//output-palindrome//
//input-he is a boy//
//output-not a palindrome//

    import java.util.*;
    class main2 
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a string");
            String str=sc.nextLine();   //he is a boy//
            int ctr=0;
            String temp="",temp1="",x="",y="";
            int i,j;
            String str1[]=str.split(" ");//[he,is,a,boy]//
            for(i=0;i<str1.length;i++)//length=4//
            {
                temp=str1[i];//reverse each word//
                for(j=temp.length()-1;j>=0;j--)
                {
                    x=x+temp.charAt(j);
                }
                x=x+" ";
            }
            System.out.println(x);

            for(int k=0;k<str1.length;k++)
            {
                temp1=str1[k]; //he//
                for(int l=temp1.length()-1;l>=0;l--)
                {
                    y=y+temp1.charAt(l);//eh//
                }
                if(y.equalsIgnoreCase(temp1))//he==eh?//
                {
                    ctr++;
                    System.out.println(y);//for printing the word//
                }
            }
            if(ctr==0)
            System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
            else
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.*;
class palindrome {
    String reverse(String str)
     {  
         String tmp="";
         int l=str.length()-1;
        for(int i=l,n=0;i>=n;i--)
        {

        tmp=tmp+str.charAt(i);
     }
        return tmp;
    }  
}
class palindrome_word{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        palindrome ob=new palindrome ();
        System.out.println("enter a sentance");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        char b;
        int i,a;
        String st="";//to extract a word
        s=s+" ";
        String t="";//to extract the reverse of the word
        a=s.length();
        System.out.println("palindrome words");
        for(i=0;i<a;i++){
            b=s.charAt(i);
            if(b!=' '){
                st=st+b;//word
               // t=b+st;reversed word
            } else { 
                t=ob.reverse(st);
                if(st.equalsIgnoreCase(t)){
                    System.out.println(st);
                }
            st="";
            t="";
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for your answer but can you explain your solution. Can you explain what you have done differently comparing Rockabyeee Java solution.